# How to use coalesce with pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, coalesce

Hello I'm trying to figure out to use coalesce with a Pivot so I can replace the NULLS with zeroes instead. Here is what I have:

```
     SELECT * FROM ( SELECT MovieTitle,AwardResultDesc, COALESCE(COUNT(p.AwardResultID),'0') AS T
     FROM tblMovie t1
            INNER JOIN tblAwardDetail p
              ON p.MovieID = t1.MovieID
            INNER JOIN tblAwardResult c
              ON c.AwardResultID = p.AwardResultID
    GROUP BY MovieTitle, AwardResultDesc,p.AwardResultID)

    PIVOT
    (
        max(T) FOR AwardResultDesc IN ('Won' AS "Won",'Nominated' AS "Nominated")
    ) 
    ORDER BY MovieTitle;
```

It seems like my Pivot is ignoring my coalesce for some reason, any suggestions?

Comment: which database you are using ?

Comment: Perhaps you need a left join to P instead of inner... do all movies have award detail? Also count returns numeric, coalesce is returning text  perhaps implicit cast failing for some reason?  Try it w/o the single quotes around the 0. and remove group by on p.awardResultID`...  Group by on what you're trying to aggregate seems incorrect.  Lastly... `IN ('Won' AS "Won",'Nominated' AS "Nominated")` aliasing in the in Statement seems incorrect.  remove aliases?

Comment: @scaisEdge I'm using oracle, right now I get the right output but the nulls are just blank, and thanks xQbert I'll try doing that in a bit I had no aliases in the pivot before but still had the same problem

Comment: The first thing I would do would be to make sure that your inner query is working correct, does that query return the data that you expect?

Comment: @xQbert Tried removing quotes from zero and removing the group by and I have the same result. Could it be something with SELECT * FROM at the beginning that cancels out the formatting of coalesce

Comment: @bluefeet♦ Yes the data that return is correct it's just the Null values are blank where as I want to replace it with zero.

Comment: @xQbert Alright I'll try that, thanks for the help

Comment: Coalesce wouldn't work is as count will always be a number 0 to x thus never null ... So coalesce seems useless here.   I don't see how you could be getting Null values.... DUH put the coalesce on the pivot, not on the inner select... `coalesce(max(t),0)` instead of on the select.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be helpful here.  Right now we're just guessing what your data and table structures look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By their nature pivot operations involve aggregate functions, so there's no need to pre-aggregate your data, however, you do need to ensure that the data you are pivoting is sufficiently complete.  Here outer joining to `tblMovie` ensures each movie is returned whether it has any award details or not. If you don't want to return counts for movies that neither won nor received nominations, then use an inner join in place of the outer join:

```
WITH dta AS (
 SELECT MovieTitle
      , AwardResultDesc
   FROM tblAwardResult ar
   JOIN tblAwardDetail ad
     ON ad.AwardResultID = ar.AwardResultID
  RIGHT JOIN tblMovie m
     ON m.MovieID = ad.MovieID
)
 SELECT *
   FROM dta
   PIVOT( count(*)
     FOR AwardResultDesc IN( 'Won' AS "Won"
                           , 'Nominated' AS "Nominated" ) )
  ORDER BY MovieTitle;
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot this query ended up working. I would never of though to not use coalesce I'm still a bit confused how it works without it. Thanks again.